# Log the warning messages in a text file from a cake script

Tags: c#, .net, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cakebuild

I'm using the below cake script to compile my `C#` project. There are few warning messages shown in `PowerShell` while executing the script. I like to log the warnings in a text file which is in a physical location(ex: `D:\WarningReport.txt)`.
The below is the cake script task I use to compile the project.

```
Task("Build")
    .Does(() =>
{
    if(IsRunningOnWindows())
    {
      MSBuild("./src/Example.sln", settings =>
        settings.SetConfiguration(configuration));
    }
});
```

I like to add something like below,

```
LogWarningMessagesTo("D:\WarningReportes.txt");
LogErrorMessagesTo("D:\ErrorReportes.txt");
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's warnings and errors from MSBuild alias you want to log that's certainly possible using the [AddFileLogger](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.MSBuild/MSBuildSettingsExtensions/FACEA8E4) extension method on the [MSBuildSettings](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.MSBuild/MSBuildSettings) parameter.

Basically change

```
  MSBuild("./src/Example.sln", settings =>
    settings.SetConfiguration(configuration));
```

to

```
MSBuild("./src/Example.sln", settings =>
    settings.SetConfiguration(configuration)
            .AddFileLogger(new MSBuildFileLogger {
                LogFile ="D:/WarningReportes.txt",
                MSBuildFileLoggerOutput = MSBuildFileLoggerOutput.WarningsOnly })
            .AddFileLogger(new MSBuildFileLogger {
                LogFile ="D:/ErrorReportes.txt",
                MSBuildFileLoggerOutput = MSBuildFileLoggerOutput.ErrorsOnly })
  );
```