# Log the warning messages into a text file from a cake script for DotNetCoreBuild

Tags: logging, .net-core, cakebuild

Is it possible to do the same thing as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271823/log-the-warning-messages-in-a-text-file-from-a-cake-script) but for DotNetCoreBuild? 
If yes, how?

[This workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51073127/cake-task-output-log-to-file) is not suitable, because I need to execute a next target and I need those logs after build step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var target = Argument("target", "Build");

var slnPath = "./src/some-project.sln";
var distDirectory = Directory("./dist");

Task("Build")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        var settings = new DotNetCoreMSBuildSettings();
        settings.FileLoggers.Add(new MSBuildFileLoggerSettings(){
            LogFile = "./WarningReportes.txt",
            SummaryOutputLevel = MSBuildLoggerOutputLevel.WarningsOnly
        });
        DotNetCoreMSBuild(slnPath, settings);
    });


RunTarget(target);
```